# Why fit results so differently when using predict()?

Tags: r

I use following fit to smooth the data:

```
lo<- loess(df_raw$`101` ~ df_raw$Scan)
```

Now, why do following two commands provide completely different fit results?

```
plot(df_raw$Scan, df_raw$`101`)
lines(lo,col='red')
```

[image: Fit1]

```
plot(df_raw$Scan, df_raw$`101`)
lines(predict(lo), col='red', lwd=2)
```

[image: Fit2]

Comment: the first plot, you are just drawing the lines for the original data. The second plot is the actual prediction.

Comment: so basically the fit object still provides the original data?

Comment: yes it is in lo$x , lo$y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the non existent differences in the following `lines()

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

iris <- iris %>% arrange(Sepal.Width)
lo <- loess(iris$Sepal.Length ~ iris$Sepal.Width)

plot(iris$Sepal.Width, iris$Sepal.Length)
lines(lo, col = "blue")
lines(lo$x, lo$y, col='red')
lines(iris$Sepal.Width, iris$Sepal.Length, col = "orange")


plot(iris$Sepal.Width, iris$Sepal.Length)
lines(predict(lo), col='blue', lwd=2)
lines(lo$fitted, col='red', lwd=2)
```